# Why Sharepoint online admin Role is missing inside our Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration

I have started working on a new Office 365 project (license is Office 365 Business Essentials). and i got a username who is defined as the Global admin for the office 365. now our customer inform us to clean the security settings for the Office 365. to make sure users do not have and will not have extra permission on the SP sites.

so now i wanted to check mainly who are the users who will have full permission on the site collections. and per my understanding all "Global admins" + "sharepoint online admins" will have a full control on all the site collections.

so to check the current user setting, i did the following steps:-

1. i login to office 365.
2. under "Users" >> "Active Users" >> i got a list of views as follow:-

[image]

now i have the following 2 concerns/questions about the current settings:-

1. inside the "Views" list i can not find the "sharepoint online admin" role. so i can not check which users have this role? as users with this role will have full control on the site collections.
2. while i find roles such as "Password admins","Service admins","User management admins" and "Billing admins" inside the Views list. so will users who are defined under those roles got full control on the site collection? or users inside these roles will not get full control on the site collection unless they have been added as site collections admins and/or are defined under the global admin group ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other admin roles which are not provided in the dropdown e.g. Exchange administrator, Sky for Business administator, PowerBI Service, Dynamic 365, etc.

You can write a powershell script to retrieve all the users assigned SharePoint administrator role.

```
Connect-MsolService
$role = Get-MsolRole -RoleName "SharePoint Service Administrator"
Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId | Export-CSV c:\temp\filename.csv
```

More details [here](http://office365support.ca/list-and-export-the-admin-roles-assigned-to-users-in-office-365-with-powershell/)

Just to mention that SharePoint administrator role doesn't only give full control to one site collection but all the site collections. Full description of this role [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/About-the-SharePoint-Online-admin-role-f08144d5-9d50-4922-8e77-4e1a27b40705?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

Comment: so there is no way to view who is the sharepoint admin,Exchange administrator, Sky for Business administator, PowerBI Service, Dynamic 365, etc. using the UI?

Comment: also the fist link you provide show how to assign users roles.. and does not show how we can view the users who have the sharepoint online roles..

Comment: Updated the answer with the actual script.

Comment: now i tried this command `#Credentials to connect to office 365 site collection url 
$url ="https://portal.office.com/adminportal/"
$userName ="*****" 
$password ="******"

Write-Host "Loading libraries"
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:Common\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:Common\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
Connect-MsolService`

Comment: but i got this error :- Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.

Comment: Ensure that PowerShell is 64bit and modules are installed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252813/connect-msolservice-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet

Comment: Now i install the libraries and then i run the command,where the `.cvs` file did not have any data. so this should mean that i do not have any "SharePoint Service Administrator" users? is this correct ?

Comment: now when i checked the users under the "Company Administator " i got 4 rows inside the .csv ... while on the UI i got 2 users only... now inside the .csv file the extra 2 users are named as "Partner app for *****" is this valid ?

Comment: Yes looks valid you might have install app which required Company Administrator permission.  Have you tried this with SharePoint Administrator role?

Comment: if i try to get the user for the "SharePoint Administrator" i will get this error :- `Get-MsolRole : This role does not exist.  Check the name and try again.`

Comment: Please use the script provided in my answer it should be 'SharePoint Service Administrator'

Comment: yes as i mentioned this will create empty csv file

Comment: So now from what i can see i have 2 global admins; our account + the customer IT manager account.. and their is not any "SharePoint Service Administrator" since the .csv file was empty... so now i can say that only the global admin can have full control on the site collections??

Comment: or there are other roles i need to check ? and what about the roles displayed inside the UI such as "Password admins","Service admins","User management admins" and "Billing admins"  ??? will they allow their users to get full control on the site collections?

Comment: You need to review my answer and the first link provided which provides all the roles.  Only SharePoint Service Administrator and Company Admin gets the full control to site collections

Comment: by Comapny Admin you mean it is the same as the Global Admin inside the UI ?? correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64436/discussion-between-sharepointer-and-john-g).